# React Nodejs page blank on reload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom, production

I pushed in production my first MERN project.

The problem is, on reload i get a `cannot GET /profile` for example.

I read that it du to react-router-dom.

So here is my code that should handle this, but I can't succeed :

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'))
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
    })
}
```

I know the first line works fine, but the second makes everything crash.

Any idea ?

Comment: Could you share error messages ?

Comment: You can see it on : https://waletoo.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Application error

Comment: It's working for me

Comment: @PankajTanwar because I took off the second line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who need, I just forgot the ```const path = require('path').